# Error when attempting to integrate with eclipse after adding spock grails plugin to project

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

After adding to BuildConfig for Grails 2.0.4 project:

```
test ":spock:0.7"
```

in the plugins { } section per the plugin documentation I wanted to update my eclipse project to include the spock libraries to create a test so I ran

```
grails integrate-with --eclipse
```

But was greeted with this

```
| Error Error executing script IntegrateWith: The Spock compiler plugin could not run because Spock 0.5.0-groovy-1.7 is not compatible with Groovy 1.8.6. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
Spock location: file:/C:/Users/fgg/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.5-groovy-1.7.jar
Groovy location: file:/C:/tools/grails-2.0.4/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up running this to fix it:

```
grails clean
```

Then ran this:

```
grails --refresh-dependencies integrate-with --eclipse
```

Got this result:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Created Eclipse project files..
```